# Grails spock test fails with "GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object"

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have a simple class that I'm writing a test for. Something weird happens when I call `validate()` on an instance of that class, which relates to my custom validator for my `date` property. If my custom validator calls a static method, everything seems to work fine. However, if I call a non-static method (which I need to as I need to check some other properties of my instance) I get the following error:

```
Condition failed with Exception:

testDate.validate(['date']) == valid
|        |
|        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate'
|           at hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate._clinit__closure1$_closure2(TestDate.groovy:20)
|           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
|           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.ValidatorConstraint.processValidate(ValidatorConstraint.java:100)
|           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:88)
|           at grails.gorm.validation.DefaultConstrainedProperty.validate(DefaultConstrainedProperty.groovy:601)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.doValidate(Validateable.groovy:192)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:163)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:129)
|           at hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDateSpec.test(TestDateSpec.groovy:15)
<hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate@48bb8764 date=null privateVar=false grails_validation_Validateable__beforeValidateHelper=org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.BeforeValidateHelper@1624fd07 grails_validation_Validateable__errors=grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors>
```

Here's my class definition:

```
@GrailsCompileStatic
class TestDate implements Validateable {
    LocalDate date
    boolean privateVar

    static constraints = {
        date nullable: true, validator: {LocalDate val -> validateDate(val)}
    }

    private validateDate(LocalDate val) {  // If this method is static, everything works fine
        return privateVar
    }
}
```

and here's my test class

```
class TestDateSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "test"() {
        given:
            TestDate testDate = new TestDate(date: date)
        expect:
            testDate.validate(['date']) == valid  // This call fails for all 4 test cases...
        where:
            date                        | valid
            null                        | true
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(1) | false
            LocalDate.now()             | false
            LocalDate.now()             | true
    }
}
```

**PS**
I have also tried without @GrailsCompileStatic but this just generates a different "cast" related error:

```
Condition failed with Exception:

testDate.validate(['date']) == valid
|        |
|        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
|           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.builder.ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java:65)
|           at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
|           at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
|           at hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate._clinit__closure1$_closure2(TestDate.groovy:19)
|           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
|           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.ValidatorConstraint.processValidate(ValidatorConstraint.java:100)
|           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.validation.constraints.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:88)
|           at grails.gorm.validation.DefaultConstrainedProperty.validate(DefaultConstrainedProperty.groovy:601)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.doValidate(Validateable.groovy:192)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:163)
|           at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:129)
|           at hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDateSpec.test(TestDateSpec.groovy:15)
<hegardt.backend.grails.model.person.TestDate@1e742012 date=null privateVar=false grails_validation_Validateable__beforeValidateHelper=org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.BeforeValidateHelper@4f3967c7 grails_validation_Validateable__errors=grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors>
```

Comment: the `validateDate()` MUST be static by design

Comment: Now that you say is, it makes sense, as the constraint block is `static`. It also says so here: https://docs.grails.org/4.0.10/guide/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to invoke an instance method (`validateDate`) from a static context (`static constraints block`) which is not allowed.  You could mark `validateDate` as `static` but that moves the problem to `privateVar` which is an instance variable so you would not be able to reach that from a `static` method.  It isn't clear what role that field plays so it isn't clear how best to deal with that, but the problem described in the question is caused because you are attempting to invoke an instance method from a static context.